# TCP RST Reset Every 5 Minutes on Windows 2003 sp2

Tags: tcp, tcpip, reset, wireshark, rst

Recently I had a web developer come to me and ask why he was receiving connection errors in his app that was accessing a sql database.

So, I went through my normal trouble shooting steps to isolate or reproduce the issue. I discovered that if I connected to the database using Query Analyzer and let the connection idle for 5 minutes it would disconnect. Meaning... I would no longer be able to refresh my tables or any other object/node within the object browser in Query Analyzer. I would have to right click on the instance and refresh for it to re-establish the connection. Next I went to wireshark and ran a capture on the client pc's nic card. Sure enough it was receiving a TCP RST reset every 5 min if the connection idled longer than 5 min. I also ran a capture on the SQL Server and noticed the TCP RST reset command as well. Attached below is the capture from the client Machine. If someone could please assist... That would be great.

-I checked all settings within SQL Server 2000 against another server and they all seem to be the same.

-Issue does not occur if I connect to any other SQL server 2000 server.

-Issue does not occur if connecting to SQL on the server itself... so only over the network.

-I consulted with network team and this is the response back:
There are no firewalls or proxies in between SQL Server and your desktop. The traffic flows like this:
Desktop->Access Switch->Distro Switch->Core Switch->Datacenter Switch->SQL Server
None of the switches have security ACL’s configured on them.
Also they stated that NAT was not turned on.

-Issue does not occur with SQL server Enterprise Manager.

-Ran SQL Profiler at the same time and did not see anything out of the ordinary during the RST

I HAVE SEARCHED HIGH AND LOW ON GOOGLE FOR A RESOLUTION FOR THIS ISSUE. NO LUCK!

My questions are:

What could be causing this?

Wrong Sequence number?

setting in a router or switch the network team may have over looked?

Setting within Windows?

Setting within SQL Server 2000 that I have over looked?

Better way to utilize Wireshark to find more answers?

RST is about 10 from the bottom.

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info

```
258 24.390708   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [SYN] Seq=0 Len=0 MSS=1260
259 24.401679   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460
260 24.401729   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
261 24.402212   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=42
262 24.413335   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=43 Win=64198 Len=37
285 24.466512   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=43 Ack=38 Win=65498 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=1260
286 24.466536   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1303 Ack=38 Win=65498 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=437
289 24.478168   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [ACK] Seq=38 Ack=1740 Win=64240 Len=0
290 24.480078   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [PSH, ACK] Seq=38 Ack=1740 Win=64240 Len=385
293 24.493629   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1740 Ack=423 Win=65113 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=60
294 24.504637   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [PSH, ACK] Seq=423 Ack=1800 Win=64180 Len=17
295 24.533197   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1800 Ack=440 Win=65096 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=44
296 24.544098   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [PSH, ACK] Seq=440 Ack=1844 Win=64136 Len=17
297 24.544524   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1844 Ack=457 Win=65079 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=58
298 24.558033   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [PSH, ACK] Seq=457 Ack=1902 Win=64078 Len=31
299 24.558493   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1902 Ack=488 Win=65048 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=92
300 24.569984   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [PSH, ACK] Seq=488 Ack=1994 Win=63986 Len=70
301 24.577395   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1994 Ack=558 Win=64978 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=448
303 24.589834   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [PSH, ACK] Seq=558 Ack=2442 Win=63538 Len=64
304 24.590122   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2442 Ack=622 Win=64914 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
305 24.601094   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [ACK] Seq=622 Ack=2443 Win=63538 Len=0
306 24.601659   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14488 [FIN, ACK] Seq=622 Ack=2443 Win=63538 Len=0
307 24.601686   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14488 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=2443 Ack=623 Win=64914 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
321 25.839371   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [SYN] Seq=0 Len=0 MSS=1260
322 25.850291   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460
323 25.850321   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
324 25.850660   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=42
325 25.861573   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=43 Win=64198 Len=37
326 25.863103   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=43 Ack=38 Win=65498 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=1260
327 25.863130   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1303 Ack=38 Win=65498 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=463
328 25.874417   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=38 Ack=1766 Win=64240 Len=0
329 25.876315   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=38 Ack=1766 Win=64240 Len=385
330 25.876905   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1766 Ack=423 Win=65113 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=60
331 25.887773   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=423 Ack=1826 Win=64180 Len=17
332 25.888299   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1826 Ack=440 Win=65096 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=44
333 25.899169   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=440 Ack=1870 Win=64136 Len=17
334 25.899574   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1870 Ack=457 Win=65079 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=58
335 25.910618   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=457 Ack=1928 Win=64078 Len=31
336 25.911051   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1928 Ack=488 Win=65048 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=92
337 25.922068   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=488 Ack=2020 Win=63986 Len=70
338 25.922500   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2020 Ack=558 Win=64978 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=34
339 25.933621   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=558 Ack=2054 Win=63952 Len=29
340 25.941165   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2054 Ack=587 Win=64949 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=54
341 25.952164   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=587 Ack=2108 Win=63898 Len=17
342 25.952993   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2108 Ack=604 Win=64932 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=72
343 25.963889   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=604 Ack=2180 Win=63826 Len=17
344 25.964366   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2180 Ack=621 Win=64915 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=52
345 25.975253   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=621 Ack=2232 Win=63774 Len=17
346 25.975590   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2232 Ack=638 Win=64898 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=32
347 25.986588   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=638 Ack=2264 Win=63742 Len=167
348 25.987262   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2264 Ack=805 Win=64731 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=512
349 25.998464   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=805 Ack=2776 Win=63230 Len=89
350 25.998861   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2776 Ack=894 Win=64642 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=46
351 26.009849   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=894 Ack=2822 Win=63184 Len=17
352 26.010175   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2822 Ack=911 Win=64625 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=80
353 26.021220   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=911 Ack=2902 Win=63104 Len=33
354 26.022613   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2902 Ack=944 Win=64592 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=498
355 26.034018   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14492 [PSH, ACK] Seq=944 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=89
356 26.046501   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [SYN] Seq=0 Len=0 MSS=1260
357 26.057323   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14493 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460
358 26.057355   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
359 26.057661   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=42
361 26.068606   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14493 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=43 Win=64198 Len=37
362 26.070087   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=43 Ack=38 Win=65498 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=1260
363 26.070113   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1303 Ack=38 Win=65498 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=485
364 26.081336   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14493 [ACK] Seq=38 Ack=1788 Win=64240 Len=0
365 26.083330   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14493 [PSH, ACK] Seq=38 Ack=1788 Win=64240 Len=385
366 26.083943   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1788 Ack=423 Win=65113 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=46
368 26.094921   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14493 [PSH, ACK] Seq=423 Ack=1834 Win=64194 Len=17
369 26.095317   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=440 Win=65096 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=48
370 26.107553   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14493 [PSH, ACK] Seq=440 Ack=1882 Win=64146 Len=877
371 26.241285   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3400 Ack=1033 Win=64503 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
372 26.241307   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      14493 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=1882 Ack=1317 Win=65535 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
653 55.913838   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
654 55.924547   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
910 85.887176   x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
911 85.898010   x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
1155 115.859520  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
1156 115.870285  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
1395 145.934403  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
1396 145.945938  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
1649 175.906767  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
1650 175.917741  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
1887 205.881080  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
1888 205.891818  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
2112 235.854408  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
2113 235.865482  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
2398 265.928342  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
2399 265.939242  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
2671 295.900714  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
2672 295.911590  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
2880 315.705029  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      2226 > 14493 [RST] Seq=1317 Len=0
2973 325.975607  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3399 Ack=1033 Win=64503 Len=1
2974 325.986337  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1033 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=0
2975 326.154327  x.x.x.10         x.x.x.99             TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 2226 > 14492 [ACK] Seq=1032 Ack=3400 Win=64240 Len=1
2976 326.154350  x.x.x.99             x.x.x.10         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] 14492 > 2226 [ACK] Seq=3400 Ack=1033 Win=64503 [TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT] Len=0
```

Comment: When you say "This issue does not occur using Enterprise manager", is Manager running on the same machine that is experiencing the timeout?  Also, are you using named pipes or TCP only connections to the server?

Comment: The capture needs to be done from both sides so the origin of the RST can be found, you could script some keep alive events but really without a cap from both sides I am just guessing so I have made this a comment not an answer,  ( EM Server Property box > connexions tab
-->Request timeout in ms)  

Also not directly related but have a look here under the sql server section: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/watch_your_timeouts.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should take a capture on the server to determine if the RST is actually sent by the server or some other intermediate device.